# How do you change Data Sets using React?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, dataset, carousel, responsive-images

I'm using a Bootstrap Carousel in react. I want to use the Carousel as a component with a data set of image information as props. However, I also want to be able to call the carousel in another component and call which data set I'd like it to use.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";
    
function PhotoCarousel() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };

  return (
    <Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect}>
      {data.map((slide, i) => {
        return (
          <Carousel.Item key={i + "-slide"}>
            <img className="d-block w-100" src={slide.image} alt={slide.alt}/>
            <Carousel.Caption>
              <h5>{slide.caption}</h5>
              <p>{slide.description}</p>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>
        );
      })}
    </Carousel>
  );
}
export default PhotoCarousel;
```

Then I have multiple data sets arranged as such

```
const oneData = [
  {
    image: "assets/images/pic.jpg",
    alt: "image-name",
    caption: "Title",
    description: "Info",
  },
];

const twoData = [
  {
    image: "assets/images/pic.jpg",
    alt: "image-name",
    caption: "Title",
    description: "Info",
  },
];
```

How do I go about modifying `{data.map((slide, i) => {return ()}}` to take a requested set when calling `<PhotoCarousel/>`?

Comment: "data set of image information as props" , you mean you don't know how to pass data to a component as `props`. In the current code, where the `data` come from?

Comment: I've created an array of data I want to be able to use the component and when called choose the selected array dataset. for instance <PhotoCarousel data={oneData}> or <PhotoCarousel data={twoData}>